# How to add a word at the beginning of each line BUT not when a # is present

Tags: regex, linux, shell, sed, sh

Given a file with many ENV variables.

Example: DEV.env

```
TRUST_STORE=/run/secret/truststore.jks
#TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD=changeit
TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD=ch@nge1t
```

I know the command `sed "s/^/export /g"` will add `export` at the beginning of each line.

But I don't want to do this when the first character is "#".

How can I do with sed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$ sed "s/^[^#]/export &/g"
export TRUST_STORE=/run/secret/truststore.jks
#TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD=changeit
export TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD=ch@nge1t
```

Alternatives:

```
$ sed "/^[^#]/ s/^/export /g"
$ sed "/^#/n; s/^/export /g"  #n : read the next line
```

Comment: Note the difference with my approach: it does not match an empty line. I understand the requirement *I don't want to do this when the first character is "#"* as the first char is either not `#` or is followed with end of string.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a regex that will capture a char other than `#` or end of line into Group 1 and then restore the value captured with a `\1` backreference

```
sed -r "s/^([^#]|$)/export \1/"
```

The `-r` option (also `-E` on some OSes) enables the POSIX ERE syntax in `sed`.

- `^` - matches start of a line
- `([^#]|$)` - a capturing group #1 matching a char other than `#` (with `[^#]`) or (`|`) end of line (`$`).

The `\1` holds the value captured with Group 1.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/7RwXw8).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak '/^[[:blank:]]*#/!s/^/export /' file

cat file
export TRUST_STORE=/run/secret/truststore.jks
#TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD=changeit
export TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD=ch@nge1t
```

Here:

- `/^[[:blank:]]*#/!`: Do this only if we have `#` at line start following optional whitespaces
- `s/^/export /`: Replace line start with `export`

Comment: `/^[[:blank:]]*#/!`: Do this only if we **DONT** have `#` at line start following optional whitespaces

Comment: It is perfectly valid to place # after few whitespaces in a line such as indented lines to comment it out.

Answer (score 0):

`echo "abc" | perl -ne 's/^(?!#)/export /g; print;'`

No capturing needed.